# Using Workflow Manager to log task times

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-workflow-manager

I'm currently updating our Workflow Manager workflow used in production.  I'd like to add a way for supervisors to track hours used on different tasks.  For instance, after an edit task is completed, the users will be prompted to enter time spent on editing.  Similarly, after a QC task is complete, the user is prompted to enter time spent on QC.  Then at the end of the day, supervisors can open a query that summarizes hours spent on each task for each job/job group/etc.

I've added a few questionnaire steps to get users to manually input their time for specific tasks.  I am aware that the results of these are stored in the JTX_HISTORY table, however, the results are stored in a manner which is (to my eye) not easily queryable for a report in WM Administrator.  Is there a method to achieve what I am trying to accomplish?